# Magento 2 - changing the Qty does not update the displayed price on product page

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, luma-theme

I just started with Magento 2. I created a configurable product with two special dropdowns.

[image: ir]

If I change the Qty, then the price does not update. It just shows 4,61 € all the time, no mather what I enter in the Qty field. Is this a bug or standard magento 2 behaviour? And why is there 0,00€ at the top? How can I fix it?

I am using the default Magento 2 Design "Luma"

**Cart:**

[image]

Comment: It just shows 4,61 € all the time because of its standard Magento 2 behavior.  for "0,00€", please check your admin panel/catalog/product - open your product and check your price, click on the advance price and check your special price. I think you should give a special price on that product. I hope it will help you.

Comment: @MonarkBhawani, Thx for your answer. The price (global) field is grayed out. There is no value inside it and I can't change it. It is a configurable product, so the price is based on the selected options. It selects a simple product linked to it, which matches my configuration and takes its price

Comment: Please check your configurable's simple product which you are selected in dropdown. and check its price or special price.

Comment: I checked it, the price is 4,61€ for 90, lfm-standard as it should be.

Comment: Please check the special price for 90, lfm-standard.

Comment: It is not set to any value...

Comment: When you add to cart, which price added in cart?.

Comment: I updated the question with a screenshot of the cart

Comment: I entered a random value to the special price field of one of the simple products linked to the configurable product , then I saved. Now it does not show the 0,00€ anymore, even after removing that random number and saving. This seems to be a magento bug.

Comment: Which Magento version you used?.

Comment: I am using Version 2.3.2

Comment: It's not Magento version 2.3.2 bug because I have not faced this issue. I am also using the default Magento 2 Design "Luma".